# Using dhcp and static ip on same nic on linux with systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I have a portabel device that sometimes needs connection to internet(to update) but will mostly be used directly connected to a laptop via ethernet cable. I want my users to have the plug and play benefits from dhcp ip when connected to a router but still be able to reach the device when no dhcp server is involved.

I basically want to do this but with systemd-networkd: 

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.130
netmask 255.255.255.0`

How do i achieve this with systemd-networkd and is there a better way to achieve same result?

Answer (score 4):

You can enable DHCP on a network interface and also set additional IPv4/IPv6 addresses.

This is an example configuration: `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[Address]
Address=192.168.0.130/24
```

It results in:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8d:c0:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.130/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86357sec preferred_lft 86357sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:c04d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`192.168.0.130` is the static IPv4, `10.0.2.15` the IPv4 from DHCP.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure dhclient.conf as follows:

```
timeout 10;

lease {
interface "eth0";
fixed-address 10.0.0.10;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}

interface "ep0" {
prepend domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
}
```

This will configure your dhcp to timeout after 10 seconds of not getting an IP address from a DHCP server and give the address 10.0.0.10 on a /24 network. You can also set DNS servers in the configuration as well. Here's a link to the man page that I got this configuration from

> http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dhclient.conf&sektion=5&n=1